# How to transform Image with CSS based on the JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, css, charts

This is the example of how it should look like on a website:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6IsK.jpg

In the gif, Chart.js is used for the Chart (Canvas)

The arrow in the middle is being rotated with the CSS transform

Let's say the JavaScript variable is "0", that would mean the arrow has to stop on the start, and if the variable is "33" it should stop at ~1/3 of the chart and so on.

And also the arrow should also change it's color the one it stops at. It needs another variable from the JavaScript.

Here is the website link where you can see the chart yourself:
http://ripskins.net/round/59891/50+otFELF0-eo4PL0md8

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something like this by using css animation **keyframes** and jquery to add class and changing the resultant color.

You can set a timeout to change the final color as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#demo").addClass("trans");
  
})
```

```css
.square
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}

.trans
{
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  animation: transrotate 2s;
}

@keyframes transrotate{

  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    background: blue;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square" id="demo">
  
</div>
```